# How to decode/deserialize Avro with Python from Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro

I am receiving from a remote server Kafka Avro messages in Python (using the consumer of Confluent Kafka Python library), that represent clickstream data with json dictionaries with fields like user agent, location, url, etc. Here is what a message looks like:

```
b'\x01\x00\x00\xde\x9e\xa8\xd5\x8fW\xec\x9a\xa8\xd5\x8fW\x1axxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\x02:https://website.in/rooms/\x02Hhttps://website.in/wellness-spa/\x02\xaa\x14\x02\x9c\n\x02\xaa\x14\x02\xd0\x0b\x02V0:j3lcu1if:rTftGozmxSPo96dz1kGH2hvd0CREXmf2\x02V0:j3lj1xt7:YD4daqNRv_Vsea4wuFErpDaWeHu4tW7e\x02\x08null\x02\nnull0\x10pageview\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x10Thailand\x02\xa6\x80\xc4\x01\x02\x0eBangkok\x02\x8c\xba\xc4\x01\x020*\xa9\x13\xd0\x84+@\x02\xec\xc09#J\x1fY@\x02\x8a\x02Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.96 Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36\x02\x10Chromium\x02\x10Chromium\x028Google Inc. and contributors\x02\x0eBrowser\x02\x1858.0.3029.96\x02"Personal computer\x02\nLinux\x02\x00\x02\x1cCanonical Ltd.'
```

How to decode it? I tried bson decode but the string was not recognized as UTF-8 as it's a specific Avro encoding I guess. I found https://github.com/verisign/python-confluent-schemaregistry but it only supports Python 2.7. Ideally I would like to work with Python 3.5+ and MongoDB to process the data and store it as it's my current infrastructure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I thought Avro library was just to read Avro files, but it actually solved the problem of decoding Kafka messages, as follow: I first import the libraries and give the schema file as a parameter and then create a function to decode the message into a dictionary, that I can use in the consumer loop.

```
import io

from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError
from avro.io import DatumReader, BinaryDecoder
import avro.schema

schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("data_sources/EventRecord.avsc").read())
reader = DatumReader(schema)

def decode(msg_value):
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict

c = Consumer()
c.subscribe(topic)
running = True
while running:
    msg = c.poll()
    if not msg.error():
        msg_value = msg.value()
        event_dict = decode(msg_value)
        print(event_dict)
    elif msg.error().code() != KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
        print(msg.error())
        running = False
```

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to import avro
`File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 27, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'open'`

Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: Where was defined io?

Comment: Just added the missing "import io" Thanks

Comment: And "open()" is a built-in Python function, so it should be callable without importing it

Comment: HI, I am using kafka-python to do the same work. I am getting following error: [avro.io.SchemaResolutionException: Can't access branch index 55 for union with 2 branches.] Also, can you please help on which avro package are you using? Thanks.

Comment: note that the method name (with avro 1.10.1, at least) is avro.schema.parse() not Parse() :)

Comment: errors out `c = Consumer() typeerror: expected configuration dict`

Answer (score 30):

If you use Confluent Schema Registry and want to deserialize avro messages, just add message_bytes.seek(5) to the decode function, since Confluent adds 5 extra bytes before the typical avro-formatted data.

```
def decode(msg_value):
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    message_bytes.seek(5)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I don't think I would have thought about that myself...

Comment: Thanks! I was blocked just by that  ;-)

Comment: Whaaaaaaat, this is crazy -- but thank you very much for the fix

Comment: You are a saviour _/\\_

Comment: how to import reader in 5th line?

Comment: @EkremGurdal check Alexandre's answer

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this! You're a hero.

Comment: See confluent wire format: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format

Comment: Thank you for this. This absolutely saved my day.

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to a Confluent schema registry server, you can also use Confluent's own `AvroDeserializer` to avoid messing with their magic 5 bytes:

```py
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro import AvroDeserializer

def process_record_confluent(record: bytes, src: SchemaRegistryClient, schema: str):
    deserializer = AvroDeserializer(schema_str=schema, schema_registry_client=src)
    return deserializer(record, None) # returns dict
```

Comment: With the caveat that `confluent_kafka` doesn't install to Python on Windows (I believe)

Comment: @bunkerdive I've got it running on WSL 2.  There are a couple of gotcha's but it works well enough for development purposes.  It's not intended for production use.  https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-and-wsl-2/

Comment: and if we don't have a Confluent schema registry server?

Comment: I like this answer, but if you have access to the schema registry server, why do you need to pass in the schema as a string in order to deserialize? I was able to remove the `schema_str` argument to `AvroDeserializer` and just pass the schema client and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding of the msg_value (c.poll().value()) was having issue in my case and using the below code to decode the value worked

```
import io
import avro
from avro.io import DatumReader, BinaryDecoder
message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg.value())
message_bytes.seek(5)
decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
schema = avro.schema.parse(jstr)
reader = DatumReader(schema)
event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
print(event_dict)
```