# Python AVRO reader returns AssertionError when decoding kafka messages

Tags: python, avro, kafka-python

Newbie playing with Kafka and AVRO. 
I am trying to deserialise AVRO messages in Python 3.7.3 using `kafka-python`, `avro-python3` packages and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44498557/4146521).

The function responsible for decoding the Kafka messages is

```
def decode_message(msg_value, reader):
    from io import BytesIO
    from avro.io import BinaryDecoder

    message_bytes = BytesIO(msg_value)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)

return event_dict
```

where `reader` is defined as `avro.io.DatumReader` instance:

```
def create_reader(filename_path):
    from avro.io import DatumReader
    import avro.schema

    schema = avro.schema.Parse(open(filename_path).read())
    reader = DatumReader(schema)

    return reader
```

Unfortunately, it fails. This is the traceback:

```
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fab73fe5530>
<avro.io.BinaryDecoder object at 0x7fab74300090>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 19, in <module>
  kfk.read_messages(kafka_consumer, avro_reader)
File "/app/modules/consume_kafka.py", line 17, in read_messages
  decoded_message = decode_message(msg_value, reader)
File "/app/modules/consume_kafka.py", line 50, in decode_message
  event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 489, in read
  return self.read_data(self.writer_schema, self.reader_schema, decoder)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 534, in read_data
  return self.read_record(writer_schema, reader_schema, decoder)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 734, in read_record
  field_val = self.read_data(field.type, readers_field.type, decoder)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 512, in read_data
  return decoder.read_utf8()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 257, in read_utf8
  input_bytes = self.read_bytes()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 249, in read_bytes
  assert (nbytes >= 0), nbytes
AssertionError: -40
```

I am able to read the message and it looks like

```
b'Obj\x01\x04\x14avro.codec\x08null\x16avro.schema\xbe\t{"type":"record","name":"tracks","namespace":"integration","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"data","type":[{"type":"record","name":"track_upload_verified","namespace":"integration.tracks","fields":[{"name":"track_id","type":"string"},{"name":"audio_filename","type":"string"},{"name":"track_type","type":"string"}]},{"type":"record","name":"audio_processed","namespace":"integration.tracks","fields":[{"name":"track_id","type":"string"},{"name":"audio_mp3_filename","type":"string"},{"name":"waveform_samples","type":{"type":"array","items":"int"}},{"name":"duration","type":"string"}]}]}]}\x00\xc4\x8ad\xceF\x9c\xef\x99\n}#y7\x96\xba\xb4\x02\xe2\x01*track_upload_verified\x00H341aa6a3-5ecb-4ac0-8f27-bc2fe5abc9d4^tracks-audio/-1khgyI4kYfSf8hq2XiXZjg-1569510465\x08main\xc4\x8ad\xceF\x9c\xef\x99\n}#y7\x96\xba\xb4'
```

which is what I expect, i.e. raw bites.

I am quite sure about the schema as I validated it using [this tool](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/avro.jsp).

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: I would suggest using the Confluent Schema Registry with their python client for dealing with Avro

Answer (score 1):

`avro-python3` is now deprecated in favor of [`avro`](https://pypi.org/project/avro/), but I'd suggest using [`fastavro`](https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead:

```py
import io

from fastavro import schemaless_reader, schemaless_writer
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer


def serialize(dict_data: dict, servo_schema: dict) -> bytes:
    """
    Serialize `dict_data` using `servo_schema` with Apache Avro.
    """
    with io.BytesIO() as bytes_writer:
        schemaless_writer(bytes_writer, servo_schema, dict_data)
        serialized_data = bytes_writer.getvalue()
    return serialized_data


def deserialize(serialized_data: bytes, servo_schema: dict) -> dict:
    """
    Deserialize `serialized_data` using `servo_schema` with Apache Avro.
    """
    with io.BytesIO() as bytes_writer:
        bytes_writer.write(serialized_data)
        bytes_writer.seek(0)
        message = schemaless_reader(bytes_writer, servo_schema)
    return message


# ...

serialized_message = serialize(message, schema)

# Send thought topic.
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=["localhost:1234"])
producer.send("my-topic", value=serialized_message)
producer.close()

# Read from topic.
consumer = KafkaConsumer("my-topic", bootstrap_servers=["localhost:1234"])
for message in consumer:
    deserialized_message = deserialize(message.value, schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a corruption within the avro file but its hard to understand based on your question and input.

Try the following:

1. install aws_schema_registry
2. from aws_schema_registry.avro import AvroSchema
3. intialise - schema = AvroSchema(my_schema)
4. now consume the bytes events comes from the kafka:
   result = schema.read(message)