# Using 'SchemaRegistryClient' to deserialize AVRO message in Python

Tags: python, schema, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We are trying to consume AVRO messages coming from other systems.
I am able to read the AVRO message when I specify the schema as a file (.avsc) using the below code,

```
import avro.schema
from avro.io import DatumReader, BinaryDecoder
...
schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("schema.avsc", "rb").read())
...
bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(element) # element is the serialized message
decoder = BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
reader = DatumReader(schema)
rec = reader.read(decoder)
```

However, I now need to read the schema from a schema registry URL instead,

```
http://<IP>:<PORT>/subjects/<SUBJECT>/versions/<VERSION>/schema
```

I am extracting the url from the incoming message custom attribute 'schema'. Now to fetch the schema from the url I am using the below code,

```
def fetch_schema(IP, subject, version):
    sr = SchemaRegistryClient(IP)
    schema = sr.get_schema(subject, version=version).schema
    return schema
```

With the same code used above to deserialize the message I now get the below error

```
AttributeError: 'AvroSchema' object has no attribute 'type'
```

on the line,

```
rec = reader.read(decoder)
```

I have compared the type of the 'schema' variable when I read from file vs. when I fetch from the URL,

```
from file, the schema type is : <class 'avro.schema.RecordSchema'>
from URL, the schema type is : <class 'schema_registry.client.schema.AvroSchema'>
```

They are different and hence probably the issue. Looking for some direction here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to get the JSON representation from the Schema Registry API call, then you can use `avro.schema.Parse` as before.

That being said, you could just use urllib or requests, and you don't need the `SchemaRegistryClient`

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same issue when converting from `avro.schema.RecordSchema` to `schema_registry.client.schema.AvroSchema`.
One possible solution could be dumping to *JSON* and then parsing it with the *Avro* library.

```py
import avro.schema
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient

client = SchemaRegistryClient(url="localhost:8081")
test_table_schema = client.get_schema("table_0_schema").schema

avro_schema = avro.schema.parse(json.dumps(test_table_schema.schema.raw_schema))

reader = DatumReader(avro_schema)
```

#### Caveat:

When working with *Kafka* and *Avro* there are also a couple of other issues that could happen:

- flush the topics of non-avro messages. I lost a lot of time decoding from *Avro* messages that were pushed with a json format because the Kafka consumer had the `auto_offset_reset='earliest'` setting.
- when working with the *Confluent* version of *Debezium*, there might be 5 bytes dedicated to the schema id. Your decoding function should look like this:

```py
def decode(msg_value):
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    message_bytes.seek(5) # <-----
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62178137/12225615) answer for more info.