# Error decode/deserialize Avro with Python from Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hello all i have debezium which listen to changes on postgres and put events on kafka topic
everything works great except i have issues decoding payloads i have tried both methods but no luck

[image]

## SQL Insert Statement

```
INSERT INTO public.student
    (id, name)
VALUES (45,'soumil 2')
```

## Docker Compose files

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    image: debezium/postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=exampledb

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.3
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.5.3
    depends_on: [zookeeper]
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9991
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"

  debezium:
    image: debezium/connect:1.4
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      GROUP_ID: 1
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_offsets
      KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
    depends_on: [kafka]
    ports:
      - 8083:8083

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.3
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema-registry:8081,http://localhost:8081
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on: [zookeeper, kafka]
```

### EXEC commands

```
docker run --tty --network debezium_default  confluentinc/cp-kafkacat kafkacat -b kafka:29092 -C -s key=s -s value=avro -r http://schema-registry:8081 -t postgres.public.student
```

## Works fine when i exec into container

[image]

## Kafka Python code

```
try:
    import kafka
    import json
    import requests
    import os
    import sys
    from json import dumps
    from kafka import KafkaProducer

    from kafka import KafkaConsumer
    from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
    import io
    from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError
    from avro.io import DatumReader, BinaryDecoder
    import avro.schema


    from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.message_serializer import MessageSerializer
    from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
    from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import (SerializerError,  # noqa
                                                 KeySerializerError,
                                                 ValueSerializerError)

    print("ALL ok")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error : {} ".format(e))

SCHEME_REGISTERY = "http://schema-registry:8081"
TOPIC = "postgres.public.student"
BROKER = "localhost:9092"

schema = """
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"Key",
   "namespace":"postgres.public.student",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"id",
         "type":"int"
      },
       {
         "name":"name",
         "type":"string"
      }
   ],
   "connect.name":"postgres.public.student.Key"
}
"""
schema = avro.schema.Parse(schema)
reader = DatumReader(schema)


def decode_method_1(msg_value):
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict


def decode_method_2(msg_value):
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    message_bytes.seek(5)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict


def fetch_schema():
    from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
    sr = SchemaRegistryClient({"url": 'http://localhost:8081'})
    subjects = sr.get_subjects()
    for subject in subjects:
        schema = sr.get_latest_version(subject)
        print(schema.version)
        print(schema.schema_id)
        print(schema.schema.schema_str)


def main():
    print("Listening *****************")

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        TOPIC,
        bootstrap_servers=[BROKER],
        auto_offset_reset='latest',
        enable_auto_commit=False,
        group_id="some group"
    )

    for msg in consumer:
        msg_value = msg.value

        print("\n")
        print("msg_value", msg_value)
        print("decode_method_1", decode_method_1(msg_value))
        print("decode_method_2", decode_method_2(msg_value))
        print("\n")


main()
```

## Outputs

```
msg_value b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x02Z\x02\x10soumil 2\x161.4.2.Final\x14postgresql\x10postgres\xac\xa6\xe4\xbc\xa9a\x00\nfalse\x12exampledb\x0cpublic\x0estudent\x02\xf4\x07\x02\xa0\x9f\xe5\x16\x00\x02c\x02\xd4\xa8\xe4\xbc\xa9a\x00'
decode_method_1 {'id': 0, 'name': ''}
decode_method_2 {'id': 0, 'name': 'Z'}
```

Your help would be great as i am not able to resolve the issue
here are some references

## References

- [How to decode/deserialize Avro with Python from Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407780/how-to-decode-deserialize-avro-with-python-from-kafka)
- https://groups.google.com/g/confluent-platform/c/A7B6uSnJa5k
- https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deserialize-avro-messages-in-python-faust-400118843447
- https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_consumer.py
- https://pypi.org/project/confluent-kafka/0.9.4/

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

```
try:
    import kafka
    import json
    import requests
    import os
    import sys
    from json import dumps
    from kafka import KafkaProducer

    from kafka import KafkaConsumer
    from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
    import io
    from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError
    from avro.io import DatumReader, BinaryDecoder
    import avro.schema

    from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.message_serializer import MessageSerializer
    from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
    from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import (SerializerError,  # noqa
                                                 KeySerializerError,
                                                 ValueSerializerError)

    print("ALL ok")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error : {} ".format(e))

SCHEME_REGISTERY = "http://schema-registry:8081"
TOPIC = "postgres.public.sales"
BROKER = "localhost:9092"

schema = """
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"Envelope",
   "namespace":"postgres.public.sales",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"before",
         "type":[
            "null",
            {
               "type":"record",
               "name":"Value",
               "fields":[
                  {
                     "name":"invoiceid",
                     "type":"int"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"itemid",
                     "type":"int"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"category",
                     "type":[
                        "null",
                        "string"
                     ],
                     "default":null
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"price",
                     "type":[
                        "null",
                        {
                           "type":"record",
                           "name":"VariableScaleDecimal",
                           "namespace":"io.debezium.data",
                           "fields":[
                              {
                                 "name":"scale",
                                 "type":"int"
                              },
                              {
                                 "name":"value",
                                 "type":"bytes"
                              }
                           ],
                           "connect.doc":"Variable scaled decimal",
                           "connect.version":1,
                           "connect.name":"io.debezium.data.VariableScaleDecimal"
                        }
                     ],
                     "doc":"Variable scaled decimal",
                     "default":null
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"quantity",
                     "type":"int"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"orderdate",
                     "type":[
                        "null",
                        {
                           "type":"long",
                           "connect.version":1,
                           "connect.name":"io.debezium.time.MicroTimestamp"
                        }
                     ],
                     "default":null
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"destinationstate",
                     "type":[
                        "null",
                        "string"
                     ],
                     "default":null
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"shippingtype",
                     "type":[
                        "null",
                        "string"
                     ],
                     "default":null
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"referral",
                     "type":[
                        "null",
                        "string"
                     ],
                     "default":null
                  }
               ],
               "connect.name":"postgres.public.sales.Value"
            }
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"after",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "Value"
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"source",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"Source",
            "namespace":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"version",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"connector",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"name",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"ts_ms",
                  "type":"long"
               },
               {
                  "name":"snapshot",
                  "type":[
                     {
                        "type":"string",
                        "connect.version":1,
                        "connect.parameters":{
                           "allowed":"true,last,false"
                        },
                        "connect.default":"false",
                        "connect.name":"io.debezium.data.Enum"
                     },
                     "null"
                  ],
                  "default":"false"
               },
               {
                  "name":"db",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"schema",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"table",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"txId",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "long"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               },
               {
                  "name":"lsn",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "long"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               },
               {
                  "name":"xmin",
                  "type":[
                     "null",
                     "long"
                  ],
                  "default":null
               }
            ],
            "connect.name":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"op",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"ts_ms",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "long"
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"transaction",
         "type":[
            "null",
            {
               "type":"record",
               "name":"ConnectDefault",
               "namespace":"io.confluent.connect.avro",
               "fields":[
                  {
                     "name":"id",
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"total_order",
                     "type":"long"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"data_collection_order",
                     "type":"long"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "default":null
      }
   ],
   "connect.name":"postgres.public.sales.Envelope"
}
"""


schema = avro.schema.Parse(schema)
reader = DatumReader(schema)


def decode_method_2(msg_value):
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    message_bytes.seek(5)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict


def fetch_schema():
    from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
    sr = SchemaRegistryClient({"url": 'http://localhost:8081'})
    subjects = sr.get_subjects()
    for subject in subjects:
        schema = sr.get_latest_version(subject)
        print(schema.version)
        print(schema.schema_id)
        print(schema.schema.schema_str)


def main():
    print("Listening *****************")

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        TOPIC,
        bootstrap_servers=[BROKER],
        auto_offset_reset='latest',
        enable_auto_commit=False,
        group_id="some group"
    )

    for msg in consumer:
        msg_value = msg.value
        print("\n")
        print("decode_method_2", decode_method_2(msg_value))
        print("\n")

main()
```

Comment: Please clarify what you changed. Don't dump code with no explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall `kafka-python`.

The Confluent deserializer in the example you've linked to automatically handles all schema registry interactions, and you don't need a schema in your consumer app.